# How can I use Visual Basic to find the size of a specific web page?

Tags: vb.net, url, web, size, filesize

I've been researching how to do this and cannot find any answers unfortunately. I would like to find the exact size of a specific web page, or if not possible, then the word/character count of a specific web page's source code.

I am doing this in order to find pages of a web site that exist, as opposed to pages that don't exist via Strings, If Statements, and For Loops by testing out every possible numeric combination after the "/" in front of the website's url, and excluding pages that are below a certain size, which would be pages that load with a 404 error, or does not exist error, which means the only resulting pages would be those that exist. These pages I am looking for have no link to them and cannot be found on a search engine. The only way to get to them is to type the exact number after the "/" to get to it, for example: (http://website.com/123456789) Perhaps this improvised brute force method will find the pages I am looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
   Dim URL As String 
    'Requesting for file details
      Dim req As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(URL)
      req.Method = "HEAD"

        'Retriving the response
      Dim resp As System.Net.WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
      Dim ContentLength As Long = 0
      Dim result As Long

        'Finding the file size
      If Long.TryParse(resp.Headers.Get("Content-Length"), ContentLength) Then
        Dim File_Size As String

        If ContentLength >= 1073741824 Then
          result = ContentLength / 1073741824

        ElseIf ContentLength >= 1048576 Then
          result = ContentLength / 1048576

        Else
          result = ContentLength / 1024

        End If
        File_Size = result.ToString("0.00")

      End If
```

Check for 404 pages

```
Private Function RemoteFileOk(ByVal Url As String) As Boolean
    Using client As New HttpClient,
        responseTask As Task(Of HttpResponseMessage) = client.GetAsync(Url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)
        responseTask.Wait()
        Using response As HttpResponseMessage = responseTask.Result
            Return response.IsSuccessStatusCode
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, but I could not get this to work properly for pages that show up with a 404 error. This only worked for pages that do exist. For example, the following url works fine, I receive a filesize from your script: (https://twitter.com/StarPartyBandUK). But if I add a "2" at the end of that url: (https://twitter.com/StarPartyBandUK2), then it no longer works because of the 404 error. However, if you go to this url on your browser, a page is generated noting that the user I am looking for does not exist. I need to be able to find the size of these 404 pages as well.

Comment: Hi, Since you are scrapping twitter u can get size of 404 page manually and put it in your code `if 404 then 100kb` or something like that

Comment: That sounds feasible, what would be the code however to call the 404 function so I can place it into the if statement? I can't just used "if 404 then 100kb"

Comment: added function check it